# Optimization of query for nested arrays

Tags: node.js, mongodb, query-optimization

My mongodb database is structured as follows:

```
[{"_id" : 1,
"main_array" : [{"subid" : 11,"date" : 2019-01-01,"details":[somearray]},
                {"subid" : 12,"date" : 2019-01-02,"details":[somearray]},
                {"subid" : 13,"date" : 2019-01-03,"details":[somearray]}]
},
{"_id" : 2,
"main_array" : [{"subid" : 21,"date" : 2019-01-01,"details":[somearray]},
                {"subid" : 22,"date" : 2019-01-02,"details":[somearray]},
                {"subid" : 23,"date" : 2019-01-03,"details":[somearray]}]
},
{"_id" : 3,
"main_array" : [{"subid" : 31,"date" : 2019-01-01,"details":[somearray]},
                {"subid" : 32,"date" : 2019-01-02,"details":[somearray]},
                {"subid" : 33,"date" : 2019-01-03,"details":[somearray]}]
}
]
```

"_id" represents user_id.The documents increase as users increase. "main array" is like a log having entries of each user for each day. I am interested in "details" array of all the users present on a particular day.

I successfully obtained the results using the following query:

```
dbase.collection("user_log").aggregate([
        {$unwind : "$main_array"},
        {$match : {"main_array.date" :2019-01-01}},
      ])
```

My doubt is that is my query optimized ?. Since i am using **unwind** in the first stage of pipeline, it might create too many documents. Will this be an issue at the later point of time when my database size increases ? Or is there any optimized way to do this ?

I am open to ideas of restructuring the database as well(if suggestions on restructure please explain the issues that might occur with the present model).

Answer (score 0):

The following data model can help you to run the required queries efficiently without aggregation queries:

**Data Model:**

```
 [{
            "_id": ObjectId(),
            "user_id": 1,
            "subid": 11,
            "date": 2019 - 01 - 01,
            "details": [somearray]
        },
        {
            "_id": ObjectId(),
            "user_id": 1,
            "subid": 12,
            "date": 2019 - 01 - 02,
            "details": [somearray]
        },
        {
            "_id": ObjectId(),
            "user_id": 1,
            "subid": 13,
            "date": 2019 - 01 - 03,
            "details": [somearray]
        },
        {
            "_id": ObjectId(),
            "user_id": 2,
            "subid": 21,
            "date": 2019 - 01 - 01,
            "details": [somearray]
        },
        {
            "_id": ObjectId(),
            "user_id": 2,
            "subid": 22,
            "date": 2019 - 01 - 02,
            "details": [somearray]
        }
    ]
```

**Queries:**

> I am interested in "details" array of all the users present on a
>   particular day.
>   The following query will return the details for a user for a day:

```
db.collection.find({user_id:1, date:2019 - 01 - 01})
```

This will avoid doing aggregations on large collections and the unwind stage.
You can avoid nested array operations with this data model.

If you want to perform user-specific aggregations later in future you can do it using [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) as the first stage of the aggregation pipeline. This will help you to have [optimized pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/#pipeline-sequence-optimization).

**Indexes:**

1. You might need to create unique indexes to avoid duplicates records for a user for a day.
2. Make sure you've right indexes in place to serve the basic find operations. e.g `{user_id:1, date:1}` in this case

Comment: Can you please explain the issue with current data structure and the query i used ?

Comment: 1. aggregations can be expensive with $unwind when used at scale unless they're optimized.  2. To get the simple details for a user for a day you're spinning up a large aggregation pipeline on an entire collection

Comment: Is it ok with adding different documents for each user each day ? In that case huge number of documents will be inserted each day when number of users increase.

Comment: agree.  With this approach you will be able to store 1095(356*3) (Note:3 is the assumed # of subid) documents per user per year. you can use TTL for older documents to expire when your collection grows large in size. 2. you can shard the collection if that grows very large in size(scalable) 3. you can archieve the data for let's say after 90 days, to offline storages if they're likely to use in future

Comment: How about using this query ?                                                                               ` dbase.collection("user_log").aggregate([
   
    {
      $project: {
          'filteredValue': {
              $filter: {
                input: "$main_array",
                as: "someObj",
                cond: { $eq: [ '$$someObj.date',2019-01-01 ] }
              }
          }
      }
  }`

Comment: This query will have similar behavior as your older query as it uses $unwind with aggregation.

Comment: Do you mean that $filter uses $unwind internally ?

Comment: This query will have similar behavior as older query uses $unwind with aggregation and the newer performs $filter without $match. Both queries are not-optimized

Comment: Does adding index to "date" field will help ?